# Measurability of restriction

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a measurable function (that is, $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}$  whenever  $B\in \mathcal{B}$).
Let $A_1,...,A_n$ be measurable subsets of $X$ such that $X=\cup A_i$.

Is it true the following equivalence: $f_{|A_1},...,f{|A_n}$ are measurable $\Leftrightarrow$ f is measurable?

I think to have proved this to be true, so I'm essencially asking a confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's true, if we use the trace

$$\mathcal{A}_i = \{A_i \cap M\colon M \in \mathcal{A}\}$$

$\sigma$-algebra on $A_i$.

The injections $\iota_i \colon A_i \hookrightarrow X$ are then measurable, and therefore $f \circ \iota_i$ is measurable for all $i$ if $f$ is measurable.

Conversely, if $f \circ \iota_i$ is measurable for all $i$, and $B \in \mathcal{B}$, then

$$f^{-1}(B) = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n \iota_i\bigl((f\lvert_{A_i})^{-1}(B)\bigr) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \iota_i(M_i)$$

is the union of finitely many measurable sets $M_i \in \mathcal{A}_i \subset \mathcal{A}$.

(The last is a little abuse of notation, strictly, $\iota_i(M_i) \in \iota_i(\mathcal{A}_i) \subset \mathcal{A}$.)